# Max message length for different transmission mediums

Tags: serial-port, ethernet, spi

I have three interfaces:

- RS422
- SPI
- Ethernet

I’m looking to generate and transmit a variable length message over the interfaces at rates up to 2KHz. I want to code checks to make sure that my output message length can be transmitted at the selected output rate for the settings of the transmission medium. I realise that this depends on the configuration of the different interfaces:

- RS422: baud rate
- SPI: clock
- Ethernet: 10Mbs or 100Mbps

As well as:

- Message length
- Transmission rate

Can anyone suggest how I can check for these fault conditions?

Answer (score 1):

Measure the bit error rate at various transmission rates and take this into consideration. You can transmit various bit patterns, collect a good sample and analyze the results to pick an ideal message size, transmission rate and integrity check/repair mechanism. Your ideal message size will likely be different for each interface.